# Torch7 DataParallelTable is not utilizing any GPU in evaluation mode

Tags: parallel-processing, torch

I am using Torch7 DataParallelTable to parallelize my Convolutional Neural Network. I based my implementation on this [example](https://github.com/soumith/imagenet-multiGPU.torch)

The DataParallelTable works great and my training time has reduced significantly. But during the validation phase (after invoking **network:evaluate()**), the network ignores GPUs and runs only on GPU (nvidia-smi shows 0% load and htop shows CPU cores burning). I am not sure what is causing this behavior. Because of this, the validation is taking a lot of time and in fact, more time than almost 10 training epochs though the size of validation set is just a quarter of the training set.
Could someone please help me in understanding this strange behaviour of DataParallelTable and fixing this issue.

I am attaching snippets from my code that are relevant to DPT and most of them are just a simple modifications from the example in the link.

**Creating DPT:**

```
function create_DataParallelNetwork(model)
print('converting module to nn.DataParallelTable')
local model_single = model
model = nn.DataParallelTable(1)
for k,v in ipairs(GPU_LIST) do
    print ('Device ',v)
cutorch.setDevice(v)
model:add(model_single:clone():cuda(), v)
end
cutorch.setDevice(params.cuda_device_train) -- *** decide on the default GPU ***
return model
end
```

**Training part: (This works fine)**

```
network:training()  -- set flag for dropout
cutorch.synchronize()
loop begins
    network:forward(input_concat)
    network:backward(input_concat, df_do)
loop ends
cutorch.synchronize()
```

**Validation part: (GPU is completely ignored here)**

```
network:evaluate()
loop begins
    network:forward(input_concat)
loop ends
```